# Prolog Combination Function

Tags: function, prolog, combinations, factorial

I was having toruble with writing a combinations function in prolog, which follows the following math equation: **b! / ((b-c)! * c!)** I am new to prolog and not sure what is entirely wrong with it. The error I receive is: **ERROR: is/2: Arithmetic: `fact1/2' is not a function**

Below is my code:

```
    %fac(0,1).
    %fac(N,X) :- N > 0, M is N - 1, fac(M,Y), X is Y * N.

    fact1(0,Result) :- Result is 1.
    fact1(N,Result) :- N > 0, N1 is N-1,                                                 
    fact1(N1,Result1), Result is Result1*N.

    main :- current_prolog_flag(argv,[BB_S,CC_S]),
        atom_number(BB_S,BB),
        atom_number(CC_S,CC),
        %read_input,
        R1 is 1,
        R2 is 1,
        R3 is 1,
        FB is fact1(BB,R1),
        ABS is abs(BB - CC),
        FE is fact1(ABS,R2),
        FC is fact1(CC,R3),
        TI is FE * FC,
        BF is FB / TI,
        %BF is fac(BB) / (fac(abs(BB-CC)) * fac(CC))),
        write($BF),
        halt.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I found a solution. But, for others benefit, I have posted the solution here. Apparently the functions dont have a return and return by placing the value they generate in a given variable.

```
    %fac(0,1).
    %fac(N,X) :- N > 0, M is N - 1, fac(M,Y), X is Y * N.

    fact1(0,Result) :- Result is 1.
    fact1(N,Result) :- N > 0, N1 is N-1, fact1(N1,Result1), Result is Result1*N.

   main :- current_prolog_flag(argv,[BB_S,CC_S]),
       atom_number(BB_S,BB),
       atom_number(CC_S,CC),
       %read_input,
       fact1(BB,FB), %notice change
       ABS is abs(BB - CC),
       fact1(ABS,FE), %notice change
       fact1(CC,FC), %notice change
       TI is FE * FC,
       BF is FB / TI,
       %BF is fac(BB) / (fac(abs(BB-CC)) * fac(CC))),
       print('Number of bracelets: '),
       write(BF),
       halt.
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the question, I think you have a misconception on what predicates are. Predicates can only result in `true` or `false` (well there can of course be an error, or they can loop forever if you see these as "possible outcomes" as well). A predicate can respond with values by *unifying* variables that are not yet fixed. Typically in Prolog, one makes predicates as generic as possible such that one can call a predicate *multidirectional*.

You call a predicate like:

```
FB is fact1(BB,R1),
```

But `fact1` is not a function (a functor for which in the `is/2` predicate, the semantics is known).

A predicate can calculate things and passes results through *unification*, for example:

```
?- fac1(5, X).
X = 120 .
```

we thus make a call to the `fac1/2` predidate with the first parameter fixed to `5`, and Prolog will unify `X` to `120`.

We can tus rewrite the predicate to:

```
main :- current_prolog_flag(argv,[BB_S,CC_S]),
    atom_number(BB_S,BB),
    atom_number(CC_S,CC),
    fact1(BB, FB),
    ABS is abs(BB - CC),
    fact1(ABS, FA),
    fact1(CC, FC),
    Res is FB / (FA * FC),
    write(Res).
```

We can also make `fac1` more declarative: right now it only works given the first parameter is fixed (or in case the second parameter is `1`). Furthermore it is a bit inefficient since it does not make use of *tail call optimization (TCO)*. We can improve the predicate by using the `clpfd` library, and implement it like:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

fac(0, 1).
fac(I, F) :-
    I #> 0,
    F #= I*F1,
    I1 #= I-1,
    fac(I1, F1).
```

Now we can query the factorial relation in several directions:

```
?- fac(I, 120).
I = 5 ;
false.

?- fac(I, 130).
false.

?- fac(5, 120).
true ;
false.

?- fac(7, 120).
false.

?- fac(7, Y).
Y = 5040 ;
false.
```

We can thus query for which `i`, `i!` is equal to `120`, etc.

We can also boost performance by implementing a product for a specific range, so:

```
  b
------
 | |
 | |   i
i=a+1
```

So a `prodrange` that is basically:

prodrange(A, B, P) :-
    fac(A, FA),
    fac(B, FB),
    P is FB / FA.

but then more efficient, since this is *O(a + b)*, and we can reduce it to *O(b - a)*, with:

```
prodrange(A, A, 1).
prodrange(A, B, P) :-
    B > A,
    B1 is B-1,
    prodrange(A, B1, P1),
    P is P1 * B1.
```

or more declarative:

```
prodrange(A, A, 1).
prodrange(A, B, P) :-
    B #> A,
    P #= B*P1,
    B1 #= B-1,
    prodrange(A, B1, P1).
```

then we can implement a `comb/3` predicate to calculate the number of combinations:

```
comb(BB, CC, Res) :-
    MX is max(BB, CC),
    MN is min(BB, CC),
    prodrange(MN, MX, Num),
    Abs is MX-MN,
    fac(Abs, Den),
    Res is Num / Den.
```

then the `main` looks like:

```
main :-
    current_prolog_flag(argv,[BB_S,CC_S]),
    atom_number(BB_S,BB),
    atom_number(CC_S,CC),
    comb(BB, CC, BF),
    print('Number of bracelets: '),
    write(BF),
    halt.
```